# how to make a horizontal scroll for a Division without vertical scroll in css

Tags: css

Here is the pattern, i need to make ul list to be left aligned with horizontal scroll if it exceeds some width like 460px without vertical scroll bar in css.

```
<div class=parentDiv>
       <ul>            //here i need to give a horizontal scroll without vertical scroll
             <li>content</li>   //  with left align
             <li>content</li>
             <li>content</li>
             <li>content</li>                
             <li>content</li> .....etc 
       </ul>    
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<div class=parentDiv>
   <ul>          
         <li>content</li>  
         <li>content</li>
         <li>content</li>
         <li>content</li>                
         <li>content</li> 
         <li>content</li> 

   </ul>    
</div>​
```

And the css

```
.parentDiv{
 width: 300px;
 overflow-x: scroll; 

 }

.parentDiv ul{
 width: 400px;
 border: 1px solid orange;

 }

 .parentDiv ul li{
 display: inline;
 margin-right: 8px;
 }
```

​

Check the fiddle I made: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2pKjW/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Give it the overflow-x: scroll property, set the max-width to 460px and you should get a horizontal scroll. I'm not sure what you mean with the left align. Isn't it left aligned?

Comment: all li should be left aligned in one line not in the second line